# Text won't show in simple android app

Tags: android-studio

So am teaching myself to develop in Android.  Using the very simple code below which I got off the web.  Figured I would build from there.  Anyway, the text shows in AndroidStudio's "design" preview.  But in the emulator and my physical tablet the text won't show.

The color values (fore and background) appear correct.  Could someone tell me what I am missing?  And if it were something blatant wouldn't it now show in the emulator as well?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Two buttons"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:allowUndo="false"
        android:layout_weight=".35" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok. Are you loading a layout in ACTIVITY by calling setContentView(R.layout.****)?

Comment: Yeah.  Like I said, it shows great in the "design preview" of AndroidStudio.  But on the emulator and a physical device, no show on the text.